# Casting a class to subclass fails

Tags: swift, parse-platform

**Edit** - Sorry guys, I don't think I gave enough detail:

In Parse's iOS framework, they is a class called **PFObject** (ClassA). The framework also allows you to subclass (ClassB) **PFObject**. AND, if a scenario such as the one I gave should occur, they would be **no** issue.

My question is how is this possible? I understand that a subclass could contain variables/methods that would not be present in the main class, thus making the process of casting a class to a subclass unreasonable/unsafe.

They have a protocol defined as PFSubclassing, but I don't see exactly how this allows this behaviour to occur.

---

I've got the following in Playground:

```
class ClassA: NSObject { }
class ClassB: ClassA { }

let objectA = ClassA()
let objectB = objectA as! ClassB // <- Crashes
```

Questions:

- Why is a crash occurring?
- Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

You do know how inheritance works right? Class B inherits from Class A. When you make an instance of ClassA and then try to cast it to class B, many different things might happen because this is undefined behavior. The problem here is what's called slicing. The compiler refuses to cast down from a parent class to a child class because it knows the child class may have different info (variables, func. etc) and it doesn't necessarily know how to translate those into an instance of a super classes child class. However, going the other way around is almost always fine, i.e

```
let objectB = ClassB()
let objectA = objectB as? ClassA
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Parse's iOS SDK somehow allows this behaviour though and I'm trying to understand how they did it. They've got a class PFObject (Class A) and allow you to make an arbitrary class (say Class B) from it. You are then allowed to cast an object of PFObject to said arbitrary class! Perhaps method swizzling is involved?

Comment: Do you mean something like `if let castedClass = classB as? PFObject?`?

Answer (score 1):

A subclass inherits all functionality from its super class and can add own functionality.

Logically you can cast types only from more to less functionality (sub -> super) but not vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Parse's iOS SDK somehow allows this behaviour though and I'm trying to understand how they did it. They've got a class PFObject (Class A) and allow you to make an arbitrary class (say Class B) from it. You are then allowed to cast an object of PFObject to said arbitrary class! Perhaps method swizzling is involved?

Comment: There must be additional logic (and specific requirements) behind the scenes to handle that.